# Tab script/code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what's a good tab script/code that will work in just about all browsers and wont conflict with jquery scripts. i was think about something like this

http://nontroppo.org/test/tab1.html

its pure css no jscript coding at all. one of that tabs will have an actually image gallery script on it another will have a video player... should I consider something with ajax or will the pure css one shown in the link about be perfect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out @ http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ as well, if you need additional handling.

Comment: that one looks pretty good. wonder what the limitations are between the jquery tabs and a pure css tab. they both will load content in from files it seems

Comment: If its only a static tabs content css would work fine. However, if you need the tabs to loaded dynamically using ajax or provide some additional handling as forms, validations JQuery tabs can provide an easier handling.